# error al guardar la imagen mi formulario en php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, html5

```php
<?php
include("conexion.php"); // para indicar que se hizo la conexion la base de datos
//petición al servidor de base de datos por método de post
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {

    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $Imagen = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['Imagen']['tmp_name']));
    $comentario = $_POST['comentario'];
    $fecha = $_POST['fecha'];
    $hora = $_POST['hora'];


    $query = "INSERT into comentarios(nombre,Imagen,comentario,fecha,hora) VALUES('$nombre','$Imagen','$comentario','$fecha','$hora')"; // insersion de datos a travez de un query
    $resultado = $conexion->query($query);

    if ($resultado) {
        echo " se inserto la base de datos";
    } else {
        echo " no se inserto la base de datos :/";
    }
}
```

> conexion exitosa. Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be
>   empty in C:\xampp2\htdocs\hostienda\datos.php on line 6 se inserto la
>   base de dato

El error me indica que se inserta la base de datos pero no la imagen en el formulario.

Comment: Faltan datos, por ejemplo, tienes realmente un campo de tipo `blob` en tu base de datos ? porque razon usas la funcion `file_get_contents()` ?

Comment: Verifica si tiene en el formulario el atributo enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: 1)si tiene un campo mediumblob, sinceramente lo vi en un tutorial que estoy aprendiendo por youtube, 2) si lo tiene

Comment: Bien. secundo lo que indica @AlexanderRodriguez, en tu formulario HTML tienes `enctype='multipart/form-data'` ?

Comment: si lo tengo @AlbertHidalgo

Answer (score 1):

No es buena idea guardar imagenes en la base de datos, lo recomendable es la siguiente logica:

- subes igual el archivo a tu servidor y lo guardas en una carpeta.
- guardas en BD el **nombre del archivo**
- cuando quieras mostrar el archivo simplemente construyes la url donde esta almacenado el archivo ejemplo: mydominio.dev/imagenes/**nombre del archivo guardado**

Comment: es buena la sugerencia pero el caso es que estoy haciéndolo de esa forma por que hace tiempo tuve una prueba de captación en la que no se contaba con Internet.Pero si tienes alguna de hacerlo de forma local tambien me gustaría saber.

Comment: Como te expliqué puedes hacerlo con internet o con tu servidor local, tu servidor local se vería algo como localhost/imagenes/nombredelarchivo.